# Do you know the reference for this law?

Tags: reference-request

I am graduate student.

As you know, the convolution operation satisfy the below equation due to commutative law.
a(n)*b(n)*c(n) = a(n)*c(n)*b(n)

In addition, the muliplication operation also satisfy the below equation due to commutative law.
a(n)b(n)c(n) = a(n)c(n)b(n)

however, to my knowledge, the below equation was not satisfied; 
a(n)b(n)*c(n) = a(n)*c(n)b(n)

Can I say that "the commutative law between multiplication operation and convolution operation does not satisfied" ?

Furthermore, do you know any reference for this phenomenon?

Comment: When you say a(n) b(n) * c(n), do you mean (a(n) b(n))*c(n), or a(n) (b(n) * c(n))? Similarly, is a(n)*c(n)b(n) equal to (a(n)*c(n))b(n), or a(n)*(c(n)b(n))? I doubt there's a reference; the fact is demonstrated by looking at nearly any choice of a, b, .

Comment: I mean, (a(n)b(n))*c(n) = (a(n)*c(n))b(n)

Comment: You almost certainly mean ‘law’, not ‘raw’, throughout.  I would call your proposed third law more a type of distributivity (though not really) than of commutativity.

Comment: @LSpice It is a kind of commutativity (or failure thereof) of operations; the operation $a \rightarrow ab$ doesn't commute with $a \rightarrow a*c$.

Comment: @user44191, I agree.  I had not noticed the [clarification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318828/do-you-know-the-reference-for-this-raw#comment794511_318828) regarding the placement of parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

*Maybe the simplest counterexample?*

Let $\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf 1}\1=1_{[0,1]}$. Then any $f\cdot\1$ is zero outside of $[0,1]$, but
$$\1*\1(x)=\int \1(t)\1(x-t)\,dt = \begin{cases}x& 0\le x\le 1\\ 2-x & 1\le x\le 2\end{cases}$$
is not. So
$$\begin{eqnarray*}(\1\cdot \1)*\1&\ne&(\1*\1)\cdot \1\quad\text{and}\\
\1\cdot (\1*\1)&\ne&\1*(\1\cdot \1).\end{eqnarray*}$$
However,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\1\cdot (\1*\1)&=&(\1*\1)\cdot \1\quad\text{and}\\
(\1\cdot \1)*\1&=&\1*(\1\cdot \1).\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.
Then, according to your counterexample, can I say that "the commutative law between multiplication operation and convolution operation does not satisfied" ?

Comment: @PILSU make sure to discuss associativity as well